# `cannot infer type` on Borrow::borrow despite constraints

Tags: rust

I want to write a piece of code that can take references or owned values of a copyable type, and return an owned version of that type. I've reduced the problems I'm having with the type inference to the following code, which errors:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn copy<R, E>(val: E) -> R
where
    R: Default + Copy,
    E: Borrow<R>,
{
    *val.borrow()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(6, copy(&6));
    assert_eq!(6, copy(6));
    assert_eq!(6.0, copy(&6.0));
    assert!((6.0f64 - copy(&6.0f64)).abs() < 1e-6);
}
```

The error comes from the last assert:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
15 |     assert!((6.0f64 - copy(&6.0f64)).abs() < 1e-6);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
```

My only hypothesis that the `Sub` trait on `f64` allows `f64` or `&f64`, and if the `Default` constraint weren't there, then a valid expression for the last copy would be `copy::<&f64, &f64>(&6.0f64)`, however that isn't allowed because `&f64` doesn't implement `Default`. If we pass in an `f64` by value it works, presumably because then it restricts `R` to be `f64` instead of either.

What I'm not clear on is why the compiler can't further restrict the return type of `copy`, or how to indicate to the compiler that the value returned won't be a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in `copy` constrains `R` to a specific concrete type. In particular, `&f64` *could* implement `Borrow<R>` for multiple values of `R` (not just `f64`). It doesn't in your current code, but the *lack of alternatives* is not considered grounds to pick a specific implementation.

I can even add an implementation that matches:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Default)]
struct Foo;

impl Borrow<Foo> for &f64 {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Foo { &Foo }
}
```

(This trait implementation is permitted even though `f64` is a standard library type because `Foo` is a type defined in the current crate.)

Now we can actually use the choice:

```rust
fn main() {
    dbg!(copy::<f64, _>(&1.0));
    dbg!(copy::<Foo, _>(&1.0));
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:19] copy::<f64, _>(&1.0) = 1.0
[src/main.rs:20] copy::<Foo, _>(&1.0) = Foo
```

A function like `copy` can only have its return type derived from its argument type when the return type *actually depends on* the argument type: for example, if it is an *associated type* of trait implemented by the argument. Both `AsRef` and `Borrow` have a type parameter rather than an associated type (and can therefore be implemented multiple times for the same implementing type); `Deref` has an associated `Target` type instead, but `Deref` doesn't offer going from `f64` to `f64`. You could implement your own trait for this:

```rust
trait DerefCopy: Copy {
    type Output;
    fn deref_copy(self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T: Copy> DerefCopy for &T {
    type Output = T;
    fn deref_copy(self) -> T {
        *self
    }
}

impl DerefCopy for f64 {
    type Output = Self;
    fn deref_copy(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(6, (&6).deref_copy());
    assert_eq!(6, (6).deref_copy());
    assert_eq!(6.0, (&6.0).deref_copy());
    assert!((6.0f64 - (&6.0f64).deref_copy()).abs() < 1e-6);
}
```

However, this would require you to implement `DerefCopy` for *every* non-reference type you wish to use it with, because it's not possible to write a blanket implementation for all *non-reference* `T`s; the reason `Borrow` *can* have a blanket implementation is that `impl Borrow<T> for T` doesn't conflict with `impl Borrow<T> for &T` because if we suppose T is itself a reference `&U`, we get `impl Borrow<&U> for &&U` which is still not the same as `impl Borrow<T> for T`.