# Why creating a local binding with Borrow in Rust makes inferring the type impossible when using borrow() on RefCell?

Tags: rust, type-inference

I try to borrow from a RefCell:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::rc::Rc;

let k = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(5)));
let what = k.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
let kk = what.borrow_mut();
```

and it works but this one doesn't:

```
let k = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(5)));
let what = k.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
let kk = what.borrow();
```

and the error message doesn't help:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed for `&Borrowed`
   --> src/bin/a.rs:404:19
    |
404 |     let kk = what.borrow();
    |         --        ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `Borrowed` declared on the trait `Borrow`
    |         |
    |         consider giving `kk` the explicit type `&Borrowed`, where the type parameter `Borrowed` is specified
    |
    = note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `Rc<RefCell<i32>>: Borrow<_>` found in the following crates: `alloc`, `core`:
            - impl<T> Borrow<T> for Rc<T>
              where T: ?Sized;
            - impl<T> Borrow<T> for T
              where T: ?Sized;
```

I don't understand why using `borrow()` doesn't work properly as `borrow_mut()` when I create a local binding with `Borrow` trait. And what should be done to borrow immutably?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466258/rust-cannot-infer-type-despite-constraints Generally, you would need to specify the `Borrowed` type because the trait supports borrowing in the form of other types (e.g. borrow `String` into `&str`). But it is kind of a surprise to see that the compiler finds no ambiguity in `borrow_mut`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you imported `Borrow`, while `borrow_mut()` refers to the inherent method of `RefCell`, `borrow()` invokes `Borrow::borrow()` on the `Rc` (it takes precedence because it is directly on the `Rc` and does not go through `Deref` to the `RefCell`). If you intended to use `RefCell::borrow()`, remove the import of `Borrow` or use fully-qualified form: `RefCell::borrow(&what)`. If you intended to use `Borrow::borrow()` (which I don't recommend to do, it is intended for generics), you need to specify the expected type as `Borrow` is generic and a type can be borrowed into multiple types (for `Rc<T>` - `Rc<T>`, `&Rc<T>` and `T`).